# Control Master volume using slider? - Xcode

Tags: xcode, loops, slider, view, volume

**Is there a way I can control the master volume using the slider?**

additional question:

is there a way for the background music to stop playing whenever i change or load views?

Thank you for the answers! :D

Answer (score 0):

if by "background music" you mean Music/iPod app which is playing, yes, you can stop it when you want.

add MediaPlayer framework to your project then use these pieces of code in your work:

**.h file**

```
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>
    {
        MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
    @end
```

**.m file**

```
@synthesize musicPlayer
```

then alloc musicplayer with

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

now you can play/pause/stop/control Music/iPod app by using:

```
[musicPlayer play]; // play
 [musicPlayer pause]; //pause
 [musicPlayer stop]; // stop
 [musicPlayer skipToPreviousItem]; //previous song
 [musicPlayer skipToNextItem]; //next song
```

you can also control its volume with a slider:

```
[slider setValue:[musicPlayer volume]];
```